# Data factory v2 filter time hour window

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I am copying my data from azure blob to sql. My azure blob is set up as `yyyy/mm/dd/hh`. I want to run an aggregation every day at 1.00AM which aggregates from raw `sql` table to another table. I am running a procedure to filter time for this aggregation, but it takes a long time to back fill the data using tumbling window as I have to run 1 copy job at a time as I can't filter my time window. My ideal situation would be copy parallely 25 hr data from azure blob and filter activity look at 1.00AM window and start aggregation job at 1.00AM.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are doing and what your problem is

Comment: what have you tried so far? any error you met?